# RDLC adding parameter to report causes report definition to change from 2008 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, rdlc, reportviewer

Using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise with SQL Server 2014. When adding a RDLC report the report definition changes from 2008 to 2016 and the report throws an error.

When I first create a blank rdlc with no datasource and open in with HTML editor, I see

```
<Report xmlns=“https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition” xmlns:rd=“https://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner”>
```

After I add a parameter with still no datasource it changes to this.

```
<Report xmlns=“https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition” xmlns:rd=“https://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner”>
```

before add parameter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKmmR.png)

after add parameter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDssG.png)

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR8G2.png)

about property
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lMLx.png)

and project properties
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEfTy.png)

Comment: Have you tried reverting it in source control and then editing it with an older version of Visual Studio, such as VS2008/2010?

Comment: Aside... XML namespaces are not URIs, although in some cases they can look like them. That is to say the correct namespaces use `http://` as opposed to `https://`, but they still aren't URIs.

Comment: I write this in visual studio 2015, and every thing is ok with 2019, just when I add a parameter to report change the line.

Comment: But whats the error? Upgrading shouldn't change anything? Maybe you need to configure your target server (in project properties) to be the level that your server is?

Comment: Pretty sure the RDLC doesn't use those fancy quotes you're showing either... seems like a strange copy and paste error.

Comment: after change this line, report is show error : an erroe occurred during local report processing. The difinition of the report is invalid. The difinition of the report is not valid or supported by this version of reporting service. The report difinition may have been created with a later version of reporting service or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on reporting services schemas. the report difinition has an invalid target namespace [1]:https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition which cannot be upgraded

Comment: also i cannot find target server (in project properties) too

Comment: [edit] the error into your question. And does the error only happen when you upload it to your server?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: add picture to discribtion.